# T4 template automatically check out output files from source control

Tags: templates, tfs, t4

I think it is common to let t4 template automatically check out files from TFS when transforming the template. But i transform the template, i got error:

Running transformation: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:******.cs' is denied.

Is there any way to overcome it?

Comment: [Damien Guard]http://damieng.com/blog/2009/11/06/multiple-outputs-from-t4-made-easy-revisited provided a helper class can check out files from TFS. It does everything i need. Perfect!

Answer (score 0):

either check out the file first, or add a prebuild step to attrib the file before building.

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to put generated files under source control. You should exclude them with .tfignore or .gitignore then delete them from your repo.

This will prevent the issue that you are experiencing.

As the files are generated on build there is no need to retain and already old version in source control.

Comment: While as a general rule, this is true, a build server may not have the access to the database it needs to run the template transform successfully.

Comment: Then you would not be trying to do the transform on the build agent and would not need write access :)

Comment: To clarify, I'm referencing a tool like entity framework.